# Unable to configure CNTLM

Tags: proxy, authentication, samba, ntlm, cntlm

I am setting up a proxy server on my linux system using CNTLM. I have edited the `cntlm.conf` file and made the following changes-

```
    #
# Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration
#
# NOTE: all values are parsed literally, do NOT escape spaces,
# do not quote. Use 0600 perms if you use plaintext password.
#

Username    myusername
Password    mypasswordinplaintext
# NOTE: Use plaintext password only at your own risk
# Use hashes instead. You can use a "cntlm -M" and "cntlm -H"
# command sequence to get the right config for your environment.
# See cntlm man page
# Example secure config shown below.
# PassLM          1AD35398BE6565DDB5C4EF70C0593492
# PassNT          77B9081511704EE852F94227CF48A793
#    #    # Only for user 'testuser', domain 'corp-uk'
# PassNTLMv2      D5826E9C665C37C80B53397D5C07BBCB

# Specify the netbios hostname cntlm will send to the parent
# proxies. Normally the value is auto-guessed.
#
# Workstation   netbios_hostname

# List of parent proxies to use. More proxies can be defined
# one per line in format <proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
#
Proxy       192.168.1.107:3128

# List addresses you do not want to pass to parent proxies
# * and ? wildcards can be used
#
NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*

# Specify the port cntlm will listen on
# You can bind cntlm to specific interface by specifying
# the appropriate IP address also in format <local_ip>:<local_port>
# Cntlm listens on 127.0.0.1:3128 by default
#
Listen      192.168.34.95:8080

# If you wish to use the SOCKS5 proxy feature as well, uncomment
# the following option. It can be used several times
# to have SOCKS5 on more than one port or on different network
# interfaces (specify explicit source address for that).
#
# WARNING: The service accepts all requests, unless you use
# SOCKS5User and make authentication mandatory. SOCKS5User
# can be used repeatedly for a whole bunch of individual accounts.
#
#SOCKS5Proxy    8010
#SOCKS5User dave:password

# Use -M first to detect the best NTLM settings for your proxy.
# Default is to use the only secure hash, NTLMv2, but it is not
# as available as the older stuff.
#
# This example is the most universal setup known to man, but it
# uses the weakest hash ever. I won't have it's usage on my
# conscience. :) Really, try -M first.
#
#Auth       LM
#Flags      0x06820000

# Enable to allow access from other computers
#
#Gateway    yes

# Useful in Gateway mode to allow/restrict certain IPs
# Specifiy individual IPs or subnets one rule per line.
#
#Allow      127.0.0.1
#Deny       0/0

# GFI WebMonitor-handling plugin parameters, disabled by default
#
#ISAScannerSize     1024
#ISAScannerAgent    Wget/
#ISAScannerAgent    APT-HTTP/
#ISAScannerAgent    Yum/

# Headers which should be replaced if present in the request
#
#Header     User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)

# Tunnels mapping local port to a machine behind the proxy.
# The format is <local_port>:<remote_host>:<remote_port>
# 
#Tunnel     11443:remote.com:443
```

Now whenever I configure Firefox's proxy setting as `192.168.34.95:3128` on a local system, it asks for user authentication. This should not happen as I have already saved my password for upstream proxy in the authentication file. My firewall is disabled, and on checking the log of cntlm, I see the following message-

```
section: global, Username = 'myusername'
section: global, Password = 'passwordinplaintext'
section: global, Proxy = '192.168.1.107:3128'
section: global, NoProxy = 'localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*'
section: global, Listen = '192.168.34.95:8080'
Resolve 192.168.34.95:
  -> 192.168.34.95
cntlm: Cannot bind port 8080: Address already in use!
Adding no-proxy for: 'localhost'
Adding no-proxy for: '127.0.0.*'
Adding no-proxy for: '10.*'
Adding no-proxy for: '192.168.*'
cntlm: No proxy service ports were successfully opened.
Exitting with error. Check daemon logs or run with -v.
```

What should I do to get `cntlm` configured properly ?

Comment: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ sounds like fun, I will try it out

Comment: From the error message above, it looks like CNTLM did not run due to a port conflict. Can you verify cntlm is running?

Comment: I am facing the same error. @IceMan CNTLM is not running.

Comment: Are you getting the same error as described in the question? I would suggest running with the -v option to get a verbose output.